# What is the remainder of $3^{2020} / 7$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I tried to solve this problem like:

Remainder of $3^2 / 7$ is $2$

Remainder of $3^3 / 7$ is $-1$

Then i square that, and I get

Remainder of $3^6 / 7$ is $1$

Then I can go all the way to:

Remainder of $3^{2016} / 7$ is $1$

Now how do I get to 2020? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

$3^{2016}=(3^6)^{336}$. The remainder is $1^{336}=1$.

$3^{2020}=3^{2016}3^4$ ...

Comment: Can you proceed now?

Comment: So the remainder then is 4 if I'm correct?

Comment: Yes. Just equal to the remainder when $81$ is divided by $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different way which does not require little Fermat in the form of $3^6 \equiv_7 1$:

\begin{eqnarray*}3^{2020} 
&\equiv_7 & 9^{1010} \\
&\equiv_7 & 2^{1010} \\
&\equiv_7 & 2^{3\cdot 336 + 2} \\
&\equiv_7 & \left(2^3\right)^{336}\cdot 2^2 \\
&\equiv_7 & 1^{336}\cdot 4 \\
&\equiv_7 & 4 \\
\end{eqnarray*}